# append XML tree as child to another XML, using PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to add an XML tree into another XML, and I have tried with following code which is not working:

```
<?php
$str1 = '<parent>
            <name>mrs smith</name>
         </parent>';

$xml1 = simplexml_load_string($str1);
print_r($xml1);

$str2 = '<tag>
             <child>child1</child>
             <age>3</age>
         </tag>';
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($str2);
print_r($xml2);

$xml1->addChild($xml2);
print_r($xml1);
?>
```

Expect output XML:

```
<parent>
    <name>mrs smith</name>
    <tag>
    <child>child1</child>
    <age>3</age>
    </tag>
</parent>
```

Please assist me.

Comment: Have you [read the manual for the `addChild()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php)? It doesn't accept a SimpleXMLEmlement object as argument.

Comment: Thanks @Magnus Eriksson  what can be done instead?please suggest

Comment: You could use the method as it's intended? :) Where does the data come from to start with?

Comment: You can use DOM for that. In DOM you can import nodes from another document and append them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DOMDocument::importNode](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php)

```
<?php 

$str2 = '<tag>
             <child>child1</child>
             <age>3</age>
         </tag>';

$str1 = '<parent>
            <name>mrs smith</name>
         </parent>';

$tagDoc = new DOMDocument;
$tagDoc->loadXML($str2);

$tagNode = $tagDoc->getElementsByTagName("tag")->item(0);
//echo $tagDoc->saveXML();

$newdoc = new DOMDocument;
$newdoc->loadXML($str1);

$node = $newdoc->importNode($tagNode, true);
$newdoc->documentElement->appendChild($node);

echo $newdoc->saveXML();die;
```